# I am programming a Numbers game, so you can bet on numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a GUI with tkinter and python 3.6, How can I add entries from a textBox and send them to another textBox? (the total textBox)

```
def btntotal() :
    Item2= var2.get()
    Total = sum(Item2)
    text2.insert(END, str(Total))
```

That doesnt work.

Comment: can you elaborate more ? what do you mean ?

Comment: Roughly is how to additione data from a textBox?  This textBox get the datas from 2 entries (2 variables) but many times, I wanna additione (sum) the entries for one of the variables.

Comment: you have two ENTRY box and want to get the SUM in the third entry box ?

Comment: this post will help you, please see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392706/building-guis-with-tkinter/46393190#46393190

Comment: Roughly is how to additione data from a textBox? This textBox get the datas from 2 entries (2 variables) but many times, I wanna additione (sum) the entries for one of the variables.

Comment: If var2.get() returns a single value, like a string, float, or integer, you cannot use sum().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much code to work with, but you should be able to adapt this:

```
def btntotal() :
    global Total   # because you are modifying the variable Total in the function namespace
    Item2 = float(var2.get())      # cast to float (or to int if you need ints)
    Total += Item2                 # update Total
    text2.insert(END, str(Total))  # Display Total in text2
```

Comment: It doesnt work return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Maxime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Stack_verse.py", line 58, in btntotal
    Item2 = int(var2.get())      # cast to float (or to int if you need ints)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 507, in get
    return int(self._tk.getdouble(value))
_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""

Comment: Yes, of course, get() returns `''` because the entry box is empty! put a float into it, and add some defensive programming to ensure the user doesn't enter random stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The below will add together the value of two `Entry` widgets if their values are both integers:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def command():
    try:
        print(int(entry1.get())+int(entry2.get()))
    except:
        None

entry1 = Entry(root)
entry2 = Entry(root)
button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=command)

entry1.pack()
entry2.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```