# Nuitka giving error with tkinter both on Linux and Mac

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, nuitka

I am working on Debian Stable Linux and have installed Nuitka application from its repositories:

```
$ nuitka --version
0.5.25
```

I am trying to create an executable with following simple tkinter gui application from [Building GUIs with Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392706/building-guis-with-tkinter)

```
import tkinter

mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()
mainWindow.title("Demo App")
# mainWindow.geometry("640x480+200+200")

entry1 = tkinter.Entry(mainWindow,width=10)
entry2 = tkinter.Entry(mainWindow,width=10)
entry1.pack()
entry2.pack()

label = tkinter.Label(mainWindow,text="Click on add to add numbers")
label.pack()

def add_values():
    result = int(entry1.get()) + int(entry2.get())
    label['text'] = result

button = tkinter.Button(mainWindow,text="Add",command=add_values)
button.pack()

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

However, it is giving following error:

```
$ nuitka-run addergui.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...addergui.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tkinter
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

If I change the import statement to:

```
import Tkinter as tkinter
```

then also I get error:

```
$ nuitka-run addergui.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../addergui.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Tkinter as tkinter
  File "/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: /lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

The application runs fine with both import commands when used with python3 and python2, respectively. I checked [Nuitka user manual](http://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html) but could not solve this.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

***Edit:***
I tried similar task on Mac. Again same problem is occurring. Tkinter is not found. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with nuitka, but it seems like you are trying to load a 64 bit dynamic library into a 32 bit program. Is there a chance you are running a 32 bit nuitka? I can run it no problem on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I am using 32 bit Debian Linux system and have installed nuitka from its repository only. I thought it would be compatible. How can I further check this?